# How to validate two textfields value in struts validation.xml file?

Tags: xml, validation, jquery, struts2, ognl

I am using Struts Jquery Ajax plugin for validation . I need to validation two textfield MinAmt and MaxAmt. I need to put validation that MaxAmt always greater than MinAmt. For that i make my XML like this.

```
<validator type="fieldexpression" short-circuit="true">
        <param name="fieldName">disSlab.maxAmt</param>
        <param name="fieldName">disSlab.minAmt</param>
        <param name="expression">disSlab.maxAmt.greaterThan(disSlab.minAmt)</param>
        <message>Not Valid Max Amt</message>
</validator>
```

But its not working. I read the [simple example here](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/form-validation-using-xml.html) and in this code

```
<validator type="fieldexpression">
    <param name="fieldname">personBean.carModels</param>
    <param name="expression"><![CDATA[personBean.carModels.length > 0]]></param>
    <message>You must select at least one car model.</message>
</validator>
```

This is working fine. but can anybody provide me an OGNL Expression for greaterthan ?

Thanks in adv
Dhrumil Shah

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<validator type="expression>
         <param name="expression">disSlab.maxAmt gt disSlab.minAmt</param>
         <message>disSlab.maxAmt must be great than disSlab.minAmt.</message>
</validator>
```

For more info see http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/validation.html#Validation-NonFieldValidatorVsFieldValidator

Comment: Its not working. i tried earlier. Do you have any other solution.

Comment: @Dhrumil Shah: are disSlab.maxAmt and disSlab.minAmt `int` or `String`?

Comment: disSlab is my VO class having getter and setter. both maxAmt and minAmt are Long type.

Answer (score 0):

Hi finally i got the solution 
If we are using a Bean and try to validate that field like disSlab.maxAmt it will not working but i changed that filed to simple maxAmt and then apply that code it working fine...
The code is like this...

```
<validator type="expression" short-circuit="true" >
      <param name="expression">maxAmt gt minAmt</param>
      <message>maxVal must be great than minVal.</message>
    </validator>
```

Dont know why this is happening..